# How to link a (subproject) framework against a pod?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I am creating a new app `MyApp`, where I decided to put some parts of the app in a seperate framework `MyFramework`, instead of the app itself to make them reusable in other projects. The framework has its own project (`MyFramework.xcodeproj`) which is a subproject of the main app project (`MyApp.xcodeproj`). The main app project has a dependency (does linking & copying) on the framework (`MyFramework.framework`), of course. This part works fine so far.

Now, `MyFramework` needs a cocoa pod (`Alamofire`) in order to work. As far as I understood, I don't want to set up cocoa pods for the `MyFramework.xcodeproj` project directly, so I just set it up for the main app `MyApp.xcodeproj` (now `MyApp.xcworkspace` because of pods) and also included the `Alamofire` pod there. I then linked `MyFramework.xcodeproj` against the `Alamofire.framework` (not the `MyApp_Pods.framework`), but did not set `Alamofire` for copying. The `MyApp.xcodeproj` does the usual cocoapods linking/copying/bundling stuff, so also includes the `Alamofire.framework` in the final product. This worked partially fine.

(Note: I say '*partially fine*' here because I occasionally had errors in the `MyFramework` sources not finding the `Alamofire` module when compiling, which could be fixed by re-linking the `Alamofire.framework` in the `MyFramework.xcodeproj`. Besides that, building and running the app works fine.)

The issue is now, when I try to archive the app, the `Alamofire` module is again not found in the `MyFramework` sources. The error occurs both, when archiving the `MyApp` (which also builds `MyFramework`), as well as archiving `MyFramework` directly. The error occurs not in the linking phase, but in the compile phase of a source Swift file that has an `import Alamofire` statement.

I suspect something like the linking of the `Alamofire.framework` to use a wrong relative path that can be found while building, but is different on archiving or such. I already tried to set the `Alamofire.framework` path to `Relative to build products`, but couldn't get this to work, not even for regular building (not archiving).

I'm now stuck and wondering whether my whole setup with linking from the `MyFramework.xcodeproj` project to the `Alamofire.framework` and having `Alamofire` included as a pod is correct.

Can anybody give me a hint what might be wrong here? Either in the paths or in the whole setup?

Answer (score 0):

This won't tackle the problem itself, but would provide a solution that serves your need:

Transform `MyFramework` into a pod. Host it in your [private spec repo](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html), or — even simpler — use the `git` parameter in the pod file to access it.

```
pod 'MyFramework', :git => 'https://gitsever/maxscompany/MyFramework.git'
```

Comment: and? did you find a solution?